# Laravel different use of where clause

Tags: laravel, model, where-clause

I want to ask about some feature in Laravel, I'm working with some old code written by someone else and I want to understand why it is written this way:

```
$users = Users::all();
$results = $users->where('age', '>','30')->get();
```

My question is how can 'where' clause be used with the '$users' variable? This works fine and no error is given and it returns the required results. But as far as i know, 'where' clause can be used like:

```
Classname::where()->get()
```

Does the User model implements some feature or use something to be able to call 'where' clause this way? When i try to do the same but with a new model i'm creating I get

```
"Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::get()
```

Comment: `$users = User::all(); $results = $users->where('age', '>', 30)->get();` is expensive from DB point of view. Use `$results = User::where('age', '>', 30)->get();` Consider case when you have 500.000 users in table and just few of them are older than 30. Calling all results first is not the way how DB engine should work.

Comment: Until not working, you can use it what ever you want. But, grab from database just what you need, not everything. I am telling you how you actually should use.

Answer (score 1):

> How can 'where' clause be used with the '$users' variable?

The where clause can be used because the [all() method](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all) returns a Collection, and the `where()` and `get()` methods are available on the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#available-methods) class.

> Does the User model implements some feature or use something to be able to call 'where' clause this way?

Each Eloquent model serves as a [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) which will make you able to add constraints and receive the results with the `get()` method afterwards.

Comment: But I get "Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::get() when i use 'where' the same way but with a different model

Comment: Are you using the `get()` method in combination with the `all()` method? That might trigger the error. If that is not the solution, please share the code that causes the exception.

Comment: No not really. I'm using it like the example above and also with $roles = $users->roles; then $roles->where('slug', 'admin')->get();

Comment: I'm still missing some context, but if a user hasMany roles, this won't work because `$users` is a collection of users, while you need a single user for whom you can load the relation. You also might need to change `$users->roles->where()` to `$users->roles()->where()`.

Comment: the user hasMany roles. but in this case, aren't we getting the roles in variable '$roles' and then applying a 'where' clause on it?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Collection::get() is diferent with QueryBuilder::get()

$builder = Users::query(); // you got QueryBuilder object
$builder->where('age', '>','30'); // you got QueryBuilder object
$list = $builder->get(); // you got Collection object
$list->where('age', '>','30'); // you got Collection object

// Collection object has 'get', but it require argument.
// QueryBuilder object has 'get' too, but do not require argument.
```

Comment: I'm also getting an error when doing  $roles = $users->roles; then $roles->where('slug', 'admin')->get(); where roles is in a relationship with users. I'm getting the same exact error "Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::get()

Comment: owh.. do you want to get the result? try:
$rolesQB = $user->roles();
$rolesQB->where('slug', 'admin');
$rolesCo = $rolesQB->get();
$roles = $rolesCo->toArray();

Comment: btw, where is the 'slug' field in DB? in users table? or in roles table?